# Issue setting up dependencies for Angular testbed with ng bootstrap elements despite importing NgbModule.forRoot()

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, testbed

I'm having trouble setting up the dependencies for a component that includes an ng bootstrap modal. The following code is from a test project that isolates the issue. The component works and runs with no errors when the website is served but there seems to be a dependency issue with the tests. I'm using the NgbModal service to open and close the modal within the component. Here's the setup of the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-component',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
  providers: [ NgbModal ]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }
```

and here's where the dependencies are set up in the app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and the dependencies for the testbed are set up in the main.component.ts file here:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MainComponent ],
      imports: [ NgbModule.forRoot(), BrowserModule ],
      providers:[ NgbModal ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    component = TestBed.get(MainComponent);
    modalService = TestBed.get(NgbModal);
  }));
```

When I try to run the tests it's giving me this error

```
Failed: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NgbModal -> NgbModalStack]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgbModal -> NgbModalStack]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbModalStack!
```

which seems to imply there's a missing dependency. With errors like this in the main app it seems like it's usually caused by the NgbModule.forRoot() not getting imported but it's in the imports for the test. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try mocking the `NgbModalStack` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've tried providing a mock for NgbModalStack as well as providing it directly and it still gives the same errors.

Comment: @A.Lynch Did you try with `NgbModalModule.forRoot()` in the imports?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue wasn't in my main component spec file, it was an issue running the test for my app component spec file. Since the component was used in the main app component it needed to have the same imports in the app component spec file.